# Remote Desktop to Azure VM not working

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I have an Azure VM created using MSDN account.
But cannot remote-desktop into it using mstsc. 
  - Tried 443 port adding on VM
  - Choose mstsc > options > settings > RD Gateway server > (entered VM name)

Any hints on how to remote to it?

Answer (score 2):

I generally download the RDP file from the portal. This has worked pretty reliably for me.

Answer (score 0):

Find the RDP endpoint port (public port) in VM settings, and RDP into that. You won't use the gateway address in the RDP client in a normal scenario, that setting is only used if you have an RD gateway server (which I'm willing to bet you don't have). So all you need is the address (cloud service URL) + port.

Or just download the RDP file, which is way easier.